# how to evaluate ( math ) a string expression, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm not sure the term I used is correct. but I have a string expression and I want it to be calculated.
this an example

```
Dim S = "4+4"
dim result = evaluate(S) 'some sort of treatment // that return 8
```

I'm not sure how this is going to work. I'm familiar with the JS eval function. but it seems that I need to add some sort of a library. and I don't want to do that. 
I have found some links about using

```
dim s = new expression("4+4")
```

and getting the result with

```
s.evaluate()
```

but that require to add another library.
and as I said before I don't want to use any library.
I just want a solution on how to proceed? I have hit a wall.
BTW I'm still a beginner try to answer as simple as you can I would appreciate it.

Comment: Whats the difference between us telling you to use SomeBuiltInThing.Eval (there isn't really anything like that) and telling you to use a 3rd party library like http://ncalc.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)-"trick":

```
Dim tbl = new DataTable()
Dim result = Convert.ToDouble(tbl.Compute("4+4", Nothing))
```

The following arithmetic operators are supported in expressions:

```
+ (addition)
- (subtraction)
* (multiplication)
/ (division)
% (modulus)
```

More informations: [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) at *Expression Syntax*.