# Get the result of a sum from a string

Tags: vb.net, sum, numbers

this is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Function AnswerQuestion(ByVal s As String) As String
        If s.Contains("How much is") Then
            Dim sum As Integer = 0
            For Each ch As Char In s
                Dim i As Integer
                If Integer.TryParse(ch, i) Then
                    sum += i
                End If
            Next
            Return "The answer is:" & sum.ToString
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(AnswerQuestion(TextBox1.Text))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want it to sum anything I put after "How much is", for example, If I put "How much is: 2 + 8" it returns 10 as a result, which is correct, but if I put "How much is: 12+5" it returns 8 instead of 17 :/ I tried to do some research but from many codes I've tried, all of them give me the same or worst result. Is there a way to do?

Comment: The **[awesome built in step debugger at your fingertips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** would help you verify that `1+2+5 = 8`

Comment: What happens if you just put `sum` instead of `sum.ToString` ?

Comment: @Plutonix I know 1+2+5=8 but I want it to take the 12 as a number instead of splitting it into 1 and 2.
SushaNaidu Ehm... It works xD idk I'm still kinda newbie with programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to evaluate ( math ) a string expression, vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392354/how-to-evaluate-math-a-string-expression-vb-net)

Comment: That's getting quite compicated. Before adding a number to the result you'd need to check that the character after this number is not a number, otherwise you go on and concatenate the next char to the current one, and so on and so on. It's getting more complicated if you want to support floating numbers as well (like How much is: 12.5+7.63)

Comment: Thanks @Nostromo I kinda figured out how to do it, Thanks Davil Wilson too, that DataTable trick also helped me a lot